# Changing privacy settings of a Facebook Group from secret to public

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-groups

How do I make the privacy of a Facebook Group that is currently set to "secret" as "public"?

I first created this group but could not make it public due to the business nature. I want to make it public, but I am unable to change its privacy settings. I already have over 1000 likes/members in the group.

How do I change the group to a public one?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the Group page
2. Click on **Edit Group** from the right
   [image]
3. From the **Privacy** drop list, select **Open**
   [image]
4. Click **Save** at the bottom of the page

Comment: it will not allow me to change the group settings..... i have tried numerous times.

Comment: @joana if the group has more than 250 members, you can't change it's settings. See the other answer.

Comment: Check this group:
http://www.facebook.com/groups/youngdloc/271810516203121/ This group has more than 30,000 ( Thirty Thousand members ) & this groups prviacy is set to CLOSED...HOW ??? HOW DID THAT BECAME POSSIBLE??

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you cannot change the privacy setting to open if the group already has 250 members or more.

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=220336891328465

Unless all members agree it's generally disrespectful to make a group open that was previously secret, since some of the members may have never joined or posted content if they knew it would be visible to everyone or broadcast to all their friends in their News Feed.  It is pretty unlikely that all members would agree with that kind of change in a group that large.

Comment: yes the group has over 1,000 members... oh shuks :'(